# Add dropdown list to cell and include it's intial value

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I want to add a dropdown list to cell A1 (which has a value of 2)
The dropdown list has a number of items ("cats", "dogs", "cheese monkeys") 
This is easy.

However, I want to included the initial cell's value (2) as part of the list dynamically. So it should look like this:

```
2
cats
dogs
cheese monkeys
```

The top value (2) needs to be changed easily (like a normal cell) AND still include the other (non dynamic) states as well.

This needs to be done without having to add extra "ghost" (hidden) reference cells on the spread sheet. This also needs to be done without VBA/macros as the file needs to be .XLSX.
Is this normal cell/dropdown list hybrid possible?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your list stored?

If you want to enter the data in cell A1 and you list is B1:B4 then just set the formula in B1 to **=A1** and you have your drop down list including the original value.

Not sure if this qualifies as a ghost cell but lists are usually stored somewhere in the worksheet.

If you just want to store it in the data validation popup I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
t = Target.Text & ","
t2 = t & "cats,dogs,cheeese monkeys"
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=t2
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = False
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then enter a value in cell **A1**.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**